# Dynamically add Materialize modal with javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, materialize

In the template page, I have an image and an input field. The image is a puzzle. If a user submits the **wrong answer** I want to show the user a modal with a message. So the modal will load only if the user submits the wrong answer.

**image**

[image]

**html**

```
<!-- show modal -->
        <div id="error" style="margin-top: 120px">
            <div id='modal1' class='modal modal-fixed-footer'></div>
        </div>

        <img class="materialboxed" width="480" height="200" src="{{ img_url }}" style="margin-top: 50px">
        <form class="" id="puzzle_form" name="puzzle_form" method="post" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>
                    <input id="answer" name="answer" type="text" class="validate" required>
                    <label for="answer">Your answer here...</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button id="submit_button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" style="margin-left: 90px">
                    Submit
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**js**

```
let _html = "<!-- Modal Structure -->";
_html += "<div class='modal-content'>";
_html += "<h4>Modal Header</h4>";
_html += "<p>A bunch of text</p>";
_html += "</div>";
_html += "<div class='modal-footer'>";
_html += "<a href='#!' class='modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat'>Agree</a>";
_html += "</div>";

$('#error').ready(function () {
    $('.modal').append(_html);
    $('.modal').modal();
});
```

But when the user submits the wrong answer, the modal is not shown in the HTML page. (It is loaded though. I can see it from the Inspect element.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `class="modal-trigger"` in your `submit` button?

Comment: @sphoenix can you add an update about your `submit_button` function?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you meant? I don't have a function name `submit_button`

Comment: the form is being submitted by `ajax` to a rest api and if the response is a failure then the above js code will be executed to load the modal

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the codepen/JSfiddle link? If you saying the html has been appended to the page and you can see it by doing inspect element. So based on this there are two possibilities:

1. If you are using a plugin for this modal, it may not have been triggered.
2. There is some issue with the CSS.

Please share a link or **CSS code**  so that I can check where it is gone wrong.Cause if it has been appended there is no issue from  HTML end. Only with triggering the modal or with CSS.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah... there's no trigger... but the things is I don't want a button to trigger the modal. I only want the modal to be opened when the user submits a wrong answer.

Comment: the ans from the user is sent to the server with ajax and if the server response is `failed` then I want to load the modal.

Comment: So in you error callback of AJAX you can trigger the modal. For example if you using bootstrap you might write this  to show it:
$("#modal").modal('show');

Comment: I'm using materialize css... here's the link https://materializecss.com/modals.html#!

Comment: That's what I'm doing!! The js code above was from the error callback of Ajax! It doesn't work, man :(

Answer (score 0):

What I did is, in my error callback in Ajax, I wrote this piece of code.

```
$('#error').ready(function () {
    $('.modal').append(_html);

    let _modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
    let instance = M.Modal.init(_modal);
    instance.open();
});
```

According to the [doc](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#), I am creating an instance of the modal by initializing it and then calling the `open` method on this instance to open the modal.